# JavaScript methods on object not updating property

Tags: javascript

I create a function that returns an object to store a number, along with some methods to manipulate the number.

```
const StoreX = (x) => ({
  x,
  add1: () => x + 1,
  inc1: () => { x += 1; },
  getX: () => x,
});

const value = StoreX(10);
```

If I run `value.add1()` a couple of times, it always returns `11`. When I inspect the `value` object, its `x` property remains as 10. This is expected as `add1()` simply returns `x + 1`.

I expect the `inc1()` method to update the `x` property of the object. But when I run the `value.inc1()` a few times, the result isn't what I expected.

```
value.inc1(); // value.x === 10
value.inc1(); // value.x === 10
value.getX(); // 12
```

So somehow `value.x` remains at 10. But if I run `value.getX()`, I do get the "correct" `12`. So `inc1()` appears to be updating some other instance of `x` that can only be retrieved by `getX()`.

What's happening here ?

Comment: `inc1` is mutating the parameter `x`, not the object property `this.x`.

Comment: arrow functions are not bind with context (`this`), so you can't use arrow function as constructor

Comment: @NobbyNobbs It's a factory function not a constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @4castle said, your functions update the `x` variable (declared by the parameter) not the `.x` object property.

You have to use either a getter to make the property live

```
function StoreX(x) {
  return {
    get x() { return x; },
    add1: () => x + 1,
    inc1: () => { x += 1; },
    getX: () => x,
  };
}
```

or methods to use the property instead of the variable

```
function StoreX(x) {
  return {
    x,
    add1() { return this.x + 1 },
    inc1() { this.x += 1; },
    getX() { return this.x },
  };
}
```

Comment: Just to add a bit of commentary on the difference between those solutions for those wondering: the first solution has more encapsulation because you can't set the internal `x` value from outside the `StoreX` function, while the second solution is more easily converted to `class` syntax, which can store the member functions once on the `prototype` object instead of duplicating them on every instance (saving memory).